# Mock Microsoft Application Insights API

Tags: unit-testing, azure, mocking, azure-application-insights

I  have an application which writes to App INsights using [custom traces/metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) and also using [REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) for reading data on to dashboard. 
**My questions is for my unit testing can I mock both custom traces(TelemetryClient) and REST API?**

I see REST API has a DEMO version but provides random information. It would be helpful if i could setup  a DEMO instrumentation key to write to and read from it for unit testing. Let me know.

Answer (score 5):

My proffered approach would be (as for any external component) to create some sort of wrapper around Telemetry Client and then it would be easy to mock it or replace it later if needed.

The other approach I would try is to use `TelemetryClient` constructor overload with `TelemetryConfiguration` and mock `TelemetryChannel`.

```
var client = new TelemetryClient(
    new TelemetryConfiguration
    {                   
         TelemetryChannel = new MOCK...
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Application Insights has an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/37cec526194b833f7cd676f25eafd985dd88d3fa/Test/CoreSDK.Test/Operation.AL.Shared.Tests/TelemetryClientExtensionAsyncTests.cs#L28-L32) of mocking `TelemetryClient` by using a `StubTelemetryChannel`.

```
var configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
this.sendItems = new List<ITelemetry>();
configuration.TelemetryChannel = new StubTelemetryChannel { OnSend = item => this.sendItems.Add(item) };
configuration.InstrumentationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking things out, it might be better to go with your second idea and actually create another application insights resource, and use the instrumentation key for that resource in the unit tests.  there's [a blog post with information about using multiple environments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/) that should head you in the right direction.

I'd suggest you even do something like that for developer/debug builds as well, so that only your "production" telemetry goes to your real instance, and then all dev/test telemetry goes to another resource instead.

Comment: Yes, it is good idea to rotate keys, only hinderance in hitting a real application for automation testing is "reading the writes" - it is not convenient because of write latency in developer mode too(about a min or 2)